# Exibir campo text no dbgrid Delphi

Tags: sql, delphi

Tenho um `DBGRID`, e preciso mostrar nele um campo do tipo *text*, porém ao mostrar, ele aparece **(MEMO)** ao invés do texto que era pra ser, como faço para fazer aparecer?

Obs: Não posso mudar o campo do Banco de Dados de `text` para `varchar`, e também já vi alguns posts falando sobre o `OnGetText` porém não achei onde fica este evento...

Segue print:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acesse o `DataSet` que fornece os dados para o *Grid*, selecione o `Field` correspondente e na aba eventos você encontrara o `OnGetText`.

Aqui usamos da seguinte forma:

```
if not Sender.IsNull then
  Text := 'Texto desejado';
```

Ali onde deixei 'Texto desejado' você pode passar da seguinte forma:

```
NomeDataSet.FieldByName('NomeDoField').AsString;
```

Para Conhecimento: Você ainda pode Manipular o Evento para os casos que não possuem dados no campo, adicionando um `else` ficando da seguinte forma:

```
if not Sender.IsNull then
  Text := 'Texto desejado'
else
  Text := 'Não existe dados gravados';
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Júnior, me ajudou demais !!!!